# webgl - model coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: matrix, 3d, webgl, cg

Im having an issue with calculating screen coordinates of a vertex. this is not a specifically a webgl issue, more of a general 3d graphics issue.

the sequence of matrix transformations that Im using is:

result_vec4 = perspective_matrix * camera_matrix * model_matrix * vertex_coords_vec4

model_matrix being the transformation of a vertex in its local coordinate system into the global scene coord system. 
so my understanding is that the final result_vec4 is in clip space? which should then be in the [-1,1] range. which is not what Im getting... result_vec4 just ends up containing some standard values for the coords, not corresponding to the correct screen position of the vertex.

does anyone have any ideas as to what might be the issue here?
thank you very much for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go in clip space you need to project `result_vec4` on the hyperplane `w=1` using:

```
result_vec4 /= result_vec4.w
```

By applying this perspective division `result_vec4.xyz` will be in [-1,1].

Comment: result_vec4.w has some "!= 1" value? Im also not clear on what you mean when you say "...providing a perspective_matrix that achieves so.".   Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: @deepblue result_vec4.w has some "!= 1" value ? does this happen after the projection (division). If so this could happen especially if the compiler pre-computes 1/w then use products. The value should be close to 1.f though. I'll remove the confusing "providing a perspective_matrix that achieves so"

Comment: the "!= 1" question I asked was confusing. everything is fine, and works as I expect it. I just thought that 'w' would aways have a 1 value, so I was confused why we should divide with 1... but thats not the value, so it works. thank you for your answer, you helped out a lot :) best.